# retainAll() on a list causes error in java

Tags: java, list, collections, set

I'm having some issues with retainAll() in java. I have a valid list as shown below. however, when I attempt to find the intersection between the two using retailAll(), it leads to the following error.

```
            String[] a = {"3", "3", "10", "4", "2", "8"};
    String[] b = {"10", "4", "12", "3", "23", "1", "8"};
    List<String> aList =  Arrays.asList(a);
    List<String> bList =  Arrays.asList(b);
    aList.retainAll(bList);
```

This exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:659)
    at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:77)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.retainAll(AbstractCollection.java:276)
    at JavaTest.main(JavaTest.java:16)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed size list. So you cannot add or remove elements.

Use the `ArrayList` constructor that takes a collection instead.

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit: The implementation returned by `Arrays.asList()` actually returns a `List` view of the array. If the caller retains a reference to the array, he can see content changes made through the `List` wrapper. That is why it is fixed size; the implementation can't throw away its backing array and create a larger one like `ArrayList` does.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the list provided does not implement the method you want.  This could be because Arrays.asList is just a stubbed out list to handle the important functions.  You might want to do the following.

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
List<String> bList =  Arrays.asList(b);
aList.retainAll(bList);
```